# Relación de uno a muchos con django

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, django, orm

Tengo estos modelos en los cuales almaceno una factura con sus descripciones.
Necesito almacenar varias descripciones asociadas a una sola factura.

```
  class Descripciones(models.Model):
    descripcion = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    referencia = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    valorUnitario = models.FloatField()
    cantidad = models.IntegerField()
    valorTotal = models.FloatField()
```

Quiero guardar dos descripciones en la misma factura

```
descripcion= Descripciones(
        descripcion=desc,
        referencia = ref,
        valorUnitario=valU,
        cantidad= canti,
        valorTotal= total
    )
    descripcion.save()

    descripcion2 = Descripciones(
        descripcion=desc2,
        referencia = ref2,
        valorUnitario=valU2,
        cantidad= canti2,
        valorTotal= total2
    )
    descripcion2.save()

factura= Factura(
        fechaInicio = fi,
        fechaFin= ff,
        cliente = cliente,
        empresa = empresa,
        descripcion = descripcion,
        resol1 =r1,
        resol2= r2,
        resol3= r3,
        resol4= r4,
        p0003= p0003,
        subTotal = st,
        descuento =0,
        totalSinIva = st,
        iva = iv,
        total = st + iv                          
    )        
    factura.save()
```

¿Cómo puedo guardar dos descripciones para una misma factura mediante una  relación de uno a muchos?

Comment: Creo que olvidaste el código

Comment: Supongo que almacenas en base de datos , te sugiero que tengas una tabla de descripciones por factura donde tengas la relación de la factura con la cantidad de descripciones que quieras, y solo con el id de la factura podras consultar todas las descripciones así sera mas fácil para manejar los datos.

Comment: Hola si lo tengo en bd y tengo dos tablas factura, y descripcion podrias darme un ejemplo por favor

Comment: Con relacion muchos a muchos se solucionaria el problema

Comment: @MateoMorales lo que debes hacer es que cada factura o registro de factura que guardas en `tbl_Facturas` tomas el id y lo guardas en `tbl_descripcion` asi relacionas la factura a las descripciones que quieras, supongo que envias una lista de descripciones, entonces recorres esa lista y por cada item realizas un registro en `Descripcion` con el id de la factura para poder saber a que factura pertenece esa descripcion

Comment: @FRANCISCOJ.BLANCO perfecto gracias por tu ayuda logré resolver el problema